# Xamarin Forms - finding databound object from custom renderer while responding to a swipe

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

From an iOS swipe event, I am trying to figure out how to work my way back to the model databound to the ViewCell (model is my own Drive object, a simple POCO).

I am using a subclassed StackLayout ...

```
public class MainPageStackLayout : StackLayout { }
```

with a custom renderer...

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MainPageStackLayout), typeof(MainPageStackLayoutRenderer))]

namespace DriveLive.iOS
{
    public class MainPageStackLayoutRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<StackLayout>
    {
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer swipeGestureRecognizer;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<StackLayout> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            swipeGestureRecognizer = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer(() =>
            {
                //********************
                Console.WriteLine("How to access the underlying model here?");
                //********************
            }) { Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left, NumberOfTouchesRequired = 1 };

            if (e.NewElement == null)
            {
                if (swipeGestureRecognizer != null)
                    this.RemoveGestureRecognizer(swipeGestureRecognizer);
            }

            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                this.AddGestureRecognizer(swipeGestureRecognizer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the code that uses the MainPageStackLayout ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DriveLive"
             x:Class="DriveLive.Views.MainPage">

  <ListView x:Name="___drives" HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate />
  </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

**C#**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        IDriveRespository repo = new DriveLive.Repository.Fakes.DriveRespository();
        ___drives.ItemsSource = repo.GetDrivesForUser(45);   // returns a Drive list of objects
        ___drives.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomViewCell));
        ___drives.SeparatorColor = Color.FromHex("#81C1B5");
    }
}

public class CustomViewCell : ViewCell
{
    bool _initialized = false;
    StackLayout _cellStack;

    public CustomViewCell()
    {
        _cellStack = new MainPageStackLayout()
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };
        View = _cellStack;

        var label = new Label() { FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold };
        label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("DestinationName"));
        _cellStack.Children.Add(label);
    }
}
```

From the handler for the UISwipeGestureRecognizer, how can I access the underlying Drive object which is databound to the ViewCell?

Comment: Can I ask what you are trying to accomplish with the swipe?

Comment: I need to set some properties in the model.

Comment: if you need to set your properties in the model when the swipe takes place then you will need to use a swipe gesture recognizer as you have. But you should put the gesture recognizer on the ListView instead of the StackLayout. Then you can use the Gesture Recognizer's `LocationInView()` method and the `IndexPathForRowAtPoint()` of the UITableView to find which row was swiped and feed it back to your model.

Comment: also if you want the swipe to reveal more actions to perform on your data row, then you can simply use ListView Context Actions which would give you the ability to identify the row out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is resolved by leveraging this piece of XForms.

[ListView Interactivity - Context Actions](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity/)

Credit goes to @skar's comment for pointing me in the right direction.